# Getting a http://repo.typesafe.com server access error when trying to start a server using activator

Tags: java, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am trying to start a play server using

```
activator -Dconfig.file=conf/prod.conf -Dhttp.port=9006 -Dhttps.port=9007 -jvm-debug 5005 run
```

But I am getting following error in the server logs:

```
...
[info] Set current project to ofe (in build file:/Users/shiva/br/work/src/analytics/frontend/ui/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/shiva/br/work/src/analytics/frontend/ui/}ofe...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.10;2.2.0 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-jdbc_2.10/2.2.0/play-jdbc_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-jdbc_2.10/2.2.0/play-jdbc_2.10-2.2.0.jar
[info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp-parent;0.8.0-rc1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/jolbox/bonecp-parent/0.8.0-rc1/bonecp-parent-0.8.0-rc1.jar
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/jolbox/bonecp-parent/0.8.0-rc1/bonecp-parent-0.8.0-rc1.jar
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.0 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java_2.10/2.2.0/play-java_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java_2.10/2.2.0/play-java_2.10-2.2.0.jar
...
```

Following is my build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0"
)

resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Server" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

play.Project.playJavaSettings

seq(copyViewsSettings:_*)
```

Following is my project/plugins.sbt file:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Maven Repo" at  "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
)

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-web" % "1.1.0")
```

I am using sbt version 0.13.18. I have cleared my ~/.ivy2/cache as well.
I want the activator command to resolve dependencies using https://repo.typesafe.com instead of http://repo.typesafe.com. But it is not clear how it is getting resolved to http://repo.typesafe.com.

I am new to play and activator. Does anyone know how to fix the above issue?